# Mockk: Stubbing same function twice ignores first behaviour

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I want to provide a `null` value for all calls with an id >= 100 -- and a concrete `Product` instance with the captured id for all others:

```
    every { repoMock.findById(more(100, true)) } returns null
    every { repoMock.findById(capture(idSlot)) } answers { Product(idSlot.captured, "Sample Product", 1.99) }
```

However the first behaviour is ignored -- for id 1234 the mock returns a Product instance.

I know I can fix it by having an `answers{..}` block with an `if` -- but what's going on here? Is the capturing behaviour ruling out all other behaviours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the capturing behaviour specifically, but simply the fact that the expression inside the second `every` matches the same (and more) cases as the first `every` does.

When you define some behaviour for a combination of a mock object and arguments, you override any previously defined behaviour for the same mock object and arguments. Since `capture(idSlot)` matches any argument, it does also match arguments `>= 100`, and therefore, it overrides the behaviour defined in the above line.

But, on the other hand, since the first `every` is indeed more specific than the second `every`, the desired behaviour can be achieved by switching the lines:

```
every { repoMock.findById(capture(idSlot)) } answers { Product(idSlot.captured, "Sample Product", 1.99) }
every { repoMock.findById(more(100, true)) } returns null
```

Then the second `every` overrides only the behaviour for a part of all combinations of `repoMock` and ids, that is, only the ones that are `>= 100`.

Comment: Yeah that works... I had tried that but had a mistake somewhere else so was misled.. :) Thx!